# Find $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{|x|}{\cos^2 (\pi/x) + 1}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, trigonometry

I need help checking/cleaning my proof of section 2.4, problem 27 of Velleman's *Calculus: A Rigorous First Course*.

Find $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{|x|}{\cos^2 (\pi/x) + 1}$.

First note that for all $x\neq0$ we have $0 \le \cos^2 (\pi/x) \iff 1 \le \cos^2 (\pi/x) + 1 \iff \frac{1}{\cos^2 (\pi/x) + 1} \le 1 \iff \frac{|x|}{\cos^2 (\pi/x) + 1} \le |x|$.

Also it's clear that for all $x\neq0$ we have $0 \le \frac{|x|}{\cos^2 (\pi/x) + 1}$ since the numerator and and denominator are both positive.

Since $0 \le \frac{|x|}{\cos^2 (\pi/x) + 1} \le |x|$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to0} 0 = \lim\limits_{x\to0} |x| = 0$, then by the Squeeze Theorem $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{|x|}{\cos^2 (\pi/x) + 1} = 0$.

Comment: Frozencoy, your proof is ok, but you should write “for all $x\neq0$” instead of “for all $x>0$”.

Comment: Your proof is very nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof seems fine. Another way to put it would be, since $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+\cos^2(\pi/x)}\in\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]$ (or, as you said, $f(x)\in[0,1]$) is bounded for $x\neq0$ and $\lim_{x\to0}|x|=0$, it follows that $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)|x|=0$ by the Squeeze Theorem.